# commander.js - .prompt removed, now what?

Tags: node.js

In [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js), when asking for user input, I would use the prompt method:

```
program.prompt('name: ', function(name){
  console.log('hi %s', name);
});
```

But now that method has been removed in version 2.0.0. What is the new method to ask for user input?

Comment: Don't upgrade to version `2.0.0` if that feature is important to you.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: looks like [promptly](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-promptly) is the new home for these functions.

This change is [being discussed in this github issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/issues/163). My guess is TJ thinks that functionality belongs in a separate module. Not sure if he plans to migrate the code to a new module or going to leave that to the community, though. But in the end probably one of these outcomes will occur:

- TJ (or someone else, possibly you) will publish a new library containing this functionality
- You can just grab the relevant code and make a library or stuff it into your project until a public module is available

Answer (score 5):

Also checkout [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/inquirer). It is inspired by `commander`, but has much more functionalities and a beautiful UI.

Answer (score 1):

Check the prompt removing commit description on [github](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/commit/bf5e1f5ec9fb1af23dd873117558575cd01d7415). Now you can use [this](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt).